# What is the Haar measure on $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lie-groups

An element of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as ($NAK$)
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&x\\
0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
y^{1/2}&0\\
0&y^{-1/2}\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with $z=x+iy$ in the upper half-plane.  In these coordinates, the invariant measure is
$$
d\theta \frac{dx dy}{y^2},
$$
the product of the invariant measures on the two subgroups, hyperbolic area (upper half-plane model) and arclength on the circle.  Is there any similar way of parametrizing a Haar measure on PSL(2,ℂ) (w.r.t some decomposition)?

Comment: Hint: Use the similar $NAK$ decomposition, where $NA$ is identified with the hyperbolic 3-space (i.e. acts isometrically and simply transitively on it).